# В строке преобразовать каждый n-й знак в верхний регистр

Tags: javascript, строки, функции, преобразование

Подскажите, как перевести каждый n-й знак строки в верхний регистр?

> Сделать функцию в которой задается параметр, который изменяет n-й символ в Верхний регистр.

**example:**

```
const text = 'I never look back';
// Каждый третий элемент
makeItFunny(text, 3); // 'I NevEr LooK bAck'
```

Мои попытки:

```
const makeItFunny = (str, char) => {
  let i = 0;

  while (i < str.length) {
    if (str[i] / char === 0){
    str[i].toUpperCase()
  }
 
    str  = i + 1;
  }

  return str;
}
```

Comment: А что вы тут вычисляете и проверяете??? `str[i] / char === 0`

Answer (score 1):

> как перевести каждый n-й знак строки в верхний регистр?

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
 const text = 'I never look back'; 
 // Каждый третий элемент 
 console.log(makeItFunny(text, 3))
 //
 function makeItFunny(t, n) {
  return Array.from(t, (s, i) => ++i % n ? s : s.toUpperCase()).join('')
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Люблю ломать мозги регулярками

```js
const makeItFunny = (str, n) => str.replace(
  new RegExp(`(.{${n - 1}})(.)`, 'g'),
  (_, a, b) => a + b.toUpperCase()
);
```

А это скучный вариант который от вас ожидают:

```js
const makeItFunny = (str, n) => {
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) % n === 0) {
      result += str[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      result += str[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответами.
Код ниже преобразует строку используя методы строк и массивов:

```js
const makeItFunny = (str, char = 2) => {
  return str
    .split('')
    .map((item, index) => !(++index % char) ? item.toUpperCase() : item)
    .join('')
}

console.log(makeItFunny('I never look back', 3))
```

[.split()](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#split-i-join) - превращает строку в массив строк(один элемент, одна буква)
[.map()](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#map) - Возвращает новый массив, преобразуя каждый элемент. В данном случае, каждый char'ый элемент будет приведен к верхнему регистру
[.join()](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#split-i-join) - преобразует массив в строку

Разбивать строку на символы и собирать новую строку мы вынуждены, т.к. [строки в javascript не изменяемые](https://learn.javascript.ru/string#stroki-neizmenyaemy)